# Hidden Input Values not being passed through form to New URL

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a small html file working in the frame of a website.  It currently requests a zip code and then calls a php page to query the database.  The iframe gets the id number from the parent page and then gets the zip code from its own page.  Here is the code snippet.

```
<script>
pid = window.location.search;
pid = pid.substring(11,16)
htmlout = '<input type = "hidden" name = "productid" id = "productid" value = "' + pid + '">';
</script>
<body style="margin: 0px; background-color: #ECECEC;">

<form action="https://www.net10wirelessphones.com/Mini-zip-Lookup.html" style="text-align: left" method = "get">
<script>
document.write(htmlout);
</script><span style="font-size: 9pt"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444">Verify coverage in your area. Enter your Zip Code: 
</span>&nbsp;     
</span>
<input name="zip" size="5" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="GO" />&nbsp;</form>
```

However, When I enter the zip code 00631, it only goes to the site 
    http://www.net10wirelessphones.com/Mini-zip-Lookup.html?zip=00631

It seems to be cutting off the hidden value from the form.  Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Edit: For those of you wanting to try it out, try it with the zip code 00631 and the product id 17637.  It should accept this option and direct to the zipsuccess page.

Edit: Also, if you want to see it from the start go to the page https://www.net10wirelessphones.com/zipstart.html?productid=17637.  Sorry I forgot to include it for those who have been trying it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the program to work.  It turns out the problem was in another form that sent to this page. I had to make a slight change to a name attribute..

This:

```
<input name="id" id="productid" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Changed to:

```
 <input name="productid" type="hidden" id="productid" value="" />
```

And it worked fine.  Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that. Here is a better alternative

```
<script>
pid = window.location.search;
pid = pid.substring(11,16)

//here is the changes
document.getElementById("productid").value = pid;
</script>

<form action="https://www.net10wirelessphones.com/Mini-zip-Lookup.html" style="text-align: left" method = "get">
<input type = "hidden" name = "productid" id = "productid" value = "" />

<span style="font-size: 9pt"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444">Verify coverage in your area. Enter your Zip Code: 
</span>&nbsp;     
</span>
<input name="zip" size="5" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="GO" />&nbsp;</form>
```

Comment: It was not getting the id from the url that was the problem (although thank you as that is a much better version than what I had).  I can inspect element and see that the productid input does have the value of whatever is being passed through, it just does not appear anywhere in the url when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I manually supplied `productid` as a GET parameter to your `zipfail.html` page. It's putting the value into the hidden input field just fine. It's also passing it to `Mini-zip-lookup.html` without flaw. It appears that either:

1. You're not be providing the `productid` in the frame's url.
2. Or the relevant code on that page is different from `zipfail.html`

Make sure the iframe's url has `?productid=?<number>` on the end.

Comment: I see you figured it out before I finished proofreading. Congrats!

Comment: I didnt, as Im trying with the address 00631, I am still only reading the address http://www.net10wirelessphones.com/Mini-zip-Lookup.html?zip=00631 without a productid attached.

Comment: If a value that is passed through a form is hidden, will it be hidden in the URL or will it appear?  If it is hidden do I need any special way to pull it from the url with php?

Comment: It will still be in the URL. Could you provide a link to the page your working on (either here or in a PM)?

Comment: Ah, I see now it was in fact your start page. Well, I'm glad you eventually figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and changing the names as stated above fixed it...to a point. I thought it might be useful to include what was actually the issue. I had my variables being set backwards. I was resetting the `$_POST` variable with a blank value every time. I was trying to add the `$_POST` values to an array and had it thus:

```
$_POST['varname'] = $my_array['varname'];
```

Once I changed it to:

```
$my_array['varname'] = $_POST['varname'];
```

It worked perfectly. Hopefully my time spend staring at this silly mistake will save someone else from doing the same.