# Set Form hidden values with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, geolocation

I am calling this function `getLocation()` on page load:

```
<script>
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
}
function showPosition(position)
{
    var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
    //alert("Your location: "+latlon);
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = coords.longitude;
}
function showError(error)
{

}
```

After that, in HTML I have defined two hidden values:

```
<FORM id="myForm" action="insertar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
    ....Some other controls...
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="">
</FORM>
```

In this function, I am setting two hidden values `latitude` and `longitude` with user's current location. But on with PHP form POST these two values are not passing. Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to check if the values are set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these 2 line should be like this

```
document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementById("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hidden Input Values not being passed through form to New URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907189/hidden-input-values-not-being-passed-through-form-to-new-url)

i searched some of relevant article and found this one most relevant. check and let me know.